# How to import a csv file to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Hello i'm trying to import a csv file that update's every 12 hours.

the format is like this http://pastebin.com/HTKfT2AF

my code is this

// this is the fastest way to load large amounts of data into MySQL

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename'
  INTO TABLE `cyberst_CSGO`.`items`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

i want to take for example the AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)  and sent it in the table cyberst_csgo with the query "name" and the 21.53 in the query "cost" and 1436821250 to the query "lastupdated"

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: and what happens now?

Comment: What works/what doesn't is what @Dagon means

Comment: When i'm trying to convert the csv file so i can sent it the page loading for about 60 seconds the the broswer pop up Time out

Comment: i would start by making the file say 10 lines long and get that working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a chance of working ultimately. You are probably facing a timeout at the php side of things.

If that is the case options include

A. `my.cnf` change such as

```
wait_timeout = 3600
interactive_timeout = 3600
```

You're on the hook for the actual values. And a mysql restart.

B. Connection-level not mysql server level tweaking of time-out

C. Smaller batches for import not a massive 1TB file